# Driving Licenses siebel Issue

Tags: regex, siebel

I have florida driving licenses like A123-123-12-123-1 and A123456789321.Now I am using below expression to show my data like XXXX-XXX-XX-XX1231.
([\s.,:])([a-zA-Z)\d{12}|([a-zA-Z)\d{3}[\s{1}-]\d{2}[\s{1}-]\d{3}[\s{1}-]\d{1}([\s.,:]).

Please let me know how can i use above expression to remove all spaces form the expresson and display the format as i mentioned above.

Thanks

Comment: You can try this regex `([\s.,:])(?:[a-zA-Z]\d{8}(\d{4})|[a-zA-Z]\d{3}[\s{1}-]\d{3}[\s{1}-]\d{2}[\s{1}-](\d{3})[\s{1}-](\d{1}))([\s.,:])` and then replace with `"$1XXXX-XXX-XX-XX$2$3$4$5"`. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a mismatch in the input and output, e.g.

```
A123-123-12-123-1
XXXX-XXX-XX-XX1231
```

there are two extra characters (ignoring dashes) in the desired output.
So assuming you want to make the output longer by repeating "12", e.g.

```
A123-123-12-123-1
A123-123-12-121231
```

Here is the code:

```
regex = /(?:[\s.,:])([a-zA-Z)(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{2})[\s-]?(\d{2})(\d{1})[\s-]?(\d{1})(?:[\s.,:])/
fixed = licence.replace(regex, "$1$2-$3-$4-$5$5$6$7")
```